# How to get coloured ribbons onto a timeseries plot in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, ribbon

I am plotting a time series from a large set of data in excel in R using:

```
plot(RiverWensum$Total.reactive.phosphorus..mg.P.L.~RiverWensum$Rdates, type="l", xlab="Time", 
ylab="Total Reactive Phosphorous (mg/L)", las=1, col="black")
abline(h = 1.003, col="red")
abline(h=0.173, col="orange")
abline(h=0.069, col="yellow")
abline(h=0.036, col="green")
```

but instead of using abline to show limits i wanted to use a ribbon tool or something to have a coloured band e.g. orange band from 0.173 to 1.003 and so on. I've done this in ggplot but I'm not sure how to in normal R plots 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to use `rect` or `polygon`, maybe there are better solutions with some packages:

```
set.seed(111)
x = 1:20
y = runif(20)
plot(x,y,type="b")
upper_y = 0.6
lower_y = 0.4
abline(h = c(upper_y,lower_y), col=c("red","red"),lty=16)
rect(min(x)-1,lower_y,max(x)+1,upper_y,col="#B2EBF21A",border=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: When i run this it comes up with:
   ' > abline(h=c(upper_yNg,lower_yNg), col=c("green","green"), lty=16)
    Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
     invalid graphics state'    
what does this error mean/how do I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: did you call the plot in the first place?

Comment: it means something is cranky with the device. did you install quartz? or what are you plotting with

Comment: Ah I think I just made an error retyping the code..is there a way to make the rectangle slightly see through - so the colour is there but the original line graph can be seen through it? Thanks

Comment: in rect(..), you set color = <something else> .. https://www.dataanalytics.org.uk/make-transparent-colors-in-r/

Comment: Ah okay, when I do that I get an error come up
CODE
> mycol <- rgb(255,0,0,max=225,alpha=125,names="red50")

Error in rgb(255, 0, 0, max = 225, alpha = 125, names = "red50") : 
  colour intensity 1.13333, not in [0,1]